# Download an APK file on SD card

Tags: external-sd, apk, downloading

I want to download an APK file to my SD card so I can take that SD card and put it in my Nook to get Google Play. I honestly don't know what I'm doing and I have an older model of the Nook Color. I only have my phone so I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: apk files can be installed on any android devices. Filename ends with an extension `.apk`. You can install downloaded apk on phones, tablets etc. Is your nook android? If so, you can install apk files on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either Your smartphone or the card reader. Insert appropriate for Your nook (apparently it is a tablet according to what Google told me. Have never encountered it before) SD/memory card in the phone/card reader and connect it to Your PC/laptop.

After downloading the needed .apk file on Your computer, copy it into a folder of the SD/memory card (for example "E:\Downloads" or any other name it will be given by the system) and disconnect the card reader/phone from comp. via safe way (most probably nothing will happen if You will simply plug it out, but just in case).

Insert the memory card (if it was in your phone in the first place - take it out beforehand. Don't forget to switch off devices when inserting/unmounting memory cards) into your nook device and switch it on. Go for the file browser (aka File Manager and so on), find the folder you have put .apk file before (Downloads folder for example) and open it via touching it's name. The system will suggest to install .apk file and demand for Your approval of the action.

That should be it, pardon if too much text/too detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading APK's(Android Package Kits) to an SD Card is trivial. It depends on the browser or the method.

These methods would include:

**Browsers**

- Chromium Based
- Mozzila Based

**Download Managers**

- Internet Download Manager

**Torrent Download Clients**

- BitTorrent
- QTorrent

**Dedicated App Store**

- Aurora Droid
- F-Droid
- Aptoide

On Android 5 and above you need to allow Storage access permissions from your devices settings. You can check out this article from Android Central that elaborates more on this topic.

[Android 5.0 Lollipop changes the way your SD card works — and that's a good thing](https://www.androidcentral.com/lollipop-brings-changes-way-your-sd-card-works-kind-youll)

After allowing access to SD Card you can change the default download location per app to select the SD Card to download apps.

For Chromium based Browsers such as Vivaldi, Edge, Brave, Opera, Chrome, and De-Googled Chromium you can change the default download storage/location from the App settings.

This method applies for most things. And most of the time all you have to do is check the apps support page to figure out to change those settings.